# How do you compare categorical responses from a branching survey when the branching is not mutually exclusive?

Tags: survey, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, survey-sampling

I have data from a survey that has a branching structure. Respondents were all asked a "select all that apply" question that included answer choices in two categories, and their answers determined which branch(es) of the survey they took. Something like this:

Q: What do you like? Select all that apply.

```
A

1

B

2
```

Anyone who chose a letter got the first branch, anyone who chose a number got the second branch, and anyone who chose both got both. The questions are the same (answer the following questions about A or B; answer the following questions about 1 or 2).

I'm trying to compare answers to similar questions across the branches. The questions are mostly 7-point Likert scales or Boolean values (from "select all that apply" questions).

I have gotten unpaired Wilcoxon Ranked Sum to work (in R: wilcox.test with paired = FALSE) but I'm struggling to decide whether that's appropriate. Will assuming these samples are independent give me unrealistically low p values?

If I'm way off here (and I may be) what would you recommend? I've been staring at this for too long and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks for your help!